# Update $scope inside .then?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function inside a controller and I'm confused as to how to update a $scope variable from inside a .then function.

Heres my function:

```
searchSpotify(query, $scope) {
    this.Spotify.search(query,'track').then(function (data) {
        console.log(data.tracks.items); // this is working
        $scope.result = data;
  }); 
}
```

In the console log I receive this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'result' of undefined
```

Do I use $scope.$apply somehow?

EDIT:

Here's the entire controller for context

```
(function() {

    class SelectionController {
        constructor(User, groupService, selectionService, songService, $scope, $routeParams, Spotify) {
            this.groupId = $routeParams.groupId;
            this.selectionId = $routeParams.selectionId;
            this.groupService = groupService;
            this.selectionService = selectionService
                //this.selections = this.selectionService.getSelections();
            this.songService = songService;
            this.searchResults;
            this.$scope = $scope;
            this.Spotify = Spotify
        }

        searchSpotify(query) {
            this.Spotify.search(query, 'track').then(function(data) {
                console.log(data.tracks.items);
                $scope.result = data;
            });
        }

        addSong(name, artist, album) {
            alert('called from selection controller');
            this.songService.addSong(this.selectionId, name, artist, album);
        }

        createSelection(name, description) {
            this.selectionService.createSelection(this.groupId, name, description);
        }

        deleteSelection(selection) {
            this.selectionService.deleteSelection(selection);
        }
    }

    angular.module('songSelectionApp')
        .controller('SelectionController', SelectionController);

})();
```

Comment: If this function is located in a controller, don't pass the $scope variable to it.

Comment: the function called by `then` as a different scope. You can use arrow function if you're using ES6, or `bind()`

Comment: when i don't pass the $scope variable in, i get the following error in the console: "ReferenceError: $scope is not defined"

Comment: Did you inject the $scope variable in your controller?

Comment: I'm going to post the whole controller

Comment: because $scope is not defined for the $scope.result $scope will work inside a controller or directive which has $scope injected manually to declare the variables using $scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save reference to $scope:

```
    searchSpotify(query) {
        var $scope = this.$scope;
        this.Spotify.search(query, 'track').then(function(data) {
            console.log(data.tracks.items);
            $scope.result = data;
        });
    }
```

Or use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
    searchSpotify(query) {
        this.Spotify.search(query, 'track').then((data) => {
            console.log(data.tracks.items);
            this.$scope.result = data;
        });
    }
```

`.bind(this)` should also work, as another answers suggest.

Regarding `$scope.$apply`: you need it only when you want to change a `$scope` outside of a `$digest`, for example when you use external (non-angular) libraries/functions, like `WebSocket`, or jquery event listeners. Untill `Spotify` is an angular service/factory - you don't need `$scope.$apply`

From [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope):

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events, setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries).

Answer (score 1):

```
this.Spotify.search(query,'track').then(function (data) {
    console.log(data.tracks.items); // this is working
    this.result = data;
}.bind($scope));
```

Should be all you need really. You are basically telling the internal scope what `this` should really be

Comment: I suppose, `$scope` is undefined. Your example will work, if you pass `.bind(this.$scope)`

Comment: i had to use .bind(this.$scope) to get this option to work

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
this.Spotify.search(query,'track').then(function (data) {
    console.log(data.tracks.items); // this is working
    this.$scope.result = data;
}.bind(this));
```